# display <b>test</b> in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jQuery and jqGrid to display data.

I want to display "**test**" in the grid as a string value, but its automatically displayed as **test** instead of correct string value. I'm using `jQuery("#notelist").jqGrid('addRowData')` to add data to the grid.

How can I overwrite this behavior?

---

I think the question is not correct. its automatically changed to bold. 
I wanted to display "`<b`> test `<b`>". instead of bold "test" in the grid. I have found the solution for this. before added to the grid I have formatted it. otherwise its automatically changed to **test** in the grid.

```
inputVal.replace(/`>/g,' &gt;'); 
inputVal.replace(/`</g,' &lt;');
```

Comment: Provide sample code. And try using custom formatter... http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter

Comment: Is the problem which you have to display bold text in one specific cell of grid? Do you know which cell should be bold at the time of filling the grid? Usage of `addRowData` is not good for filling the grid, but in all scenarios one can suggest the solution of your problem. You should describe more detailed what you do because the best solution can be different depend on the scenario which you have.